# How can I add a permissions callback to the REST API index pages?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'd like to block unauthenticated users from accessing the index JSON pages, such as /wp-json and /wp-json/myplugin/v1. Is there a way for me to do this? I currently just have everything except the login page blocked for all unauthenticated users, but there are a few other pages I'd like to add and I don't want to end up with a long whitelist to maintain.

Comment: Note that those pages only list the endpoints that the user has access to, if you make all the endpoints under `wp-json/myplugin/v1` require a login, then nothing will be listed to logged out users, that route may not even be accessible. So if your goal is to conceal endpoints to users who shouldn't be using them, then the REST API already does that, you just need to secure your endpoints

Comment: I just successfully viewed all endpoints in a private window with no login. Nearly all of them have `permission_callback`s that require a user to be logged in.

Comment: and visiting those endpoints without being logged in works?